# When can a function return a reference?

Tags: rust, reference, ownership

I was experimenting with Rust, and found an oddity that I cannot understand. Usually, the compiler prohibits a function from returning a reference without a static lifetime (e.g. `String` or `&'static str`, but never `&str`).

However, this code compiled and worked:

```
fn f(_: &Vec<u8>) -> &str {
    "Hello, world!"
}
```

Whereas this code did not:

```
fn f() -> &str {
    "Hello, world!"
}
```

Why does the first function work when it is returning a reference to a dropped value?

Comment: put it **simply**, you can return a reference when the function take a reference as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) which doesn't work on functions without input parameters.

The first method is expanded to this:

```
fn f<'a>(_: &'a Vec<u8>) -> &'a str {
```

The second method is the 'ILLEGAL' example from the linked doc.

So you have to define it yourself:

```
fn f<'a>() -> &'a str {
```

...or static:

```
fn f() -> &'static str {
```

Comment: Ah ok, I think my understanding of lifetimes was Rusty, thanks for clearing it up.